# how to remove background

Tags: image

Hi i want to remove the black background from the image attach. I just want to remove the background and give an outline or border to the image remaing and save in transparent png format. How can i make is there any quick way to remove the background. Any suggestion or Help. Thanks

[image]

Comment: This question is not about Blender but image editing. There are the freeware alternatives *Gimp* or *Krita* which will  be suitable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about image editing, not Blender.

Answer (score 2):

First go into Blender's "Node Editor," and switch it to the compositor editor (using the button with two photographs on it at the bottom of the screen). Check the "Use Nodes" box, and delete the "Render Layer" node. Add an "Image" node, and use it to open your desired image. Drag the *image* output into the *image* input of the "Compositor" node, and create a new "Brightness / Contrast" and "Color Ramp" node. Attach the *image* output of the "Image" node to the *image* input of the "Bright / Contrast" node, set the contrast to `20` and attach the *image* output to the *fac* input of the "Color Ramp" node. Create a new color stop that is completely white, and change its position to .0001. Finally, connect the *image* output to the alpha input of the "Compositor" node.

What this does is it isolates the black in the image, and makes every section that is black completely transparent. The layout should look like this: [image]

Back in the "3D View" tab, delete everything in the scene by pressing A and then X. In the "Render" panel, set the resolution to that of your desired image, and set the samples down to 0. Give that baby a render, and everything should look correct. Select "Image > Save As Image" to save the final result. It should look like this: [image] [image]

This is sort of an inconvenient, and imprecise, way to delete an image's background, however. Blender isn't really designed for this kinda thing. I recommend going into Adobe Photoshop instead, and using the "Magnetic Lasso" tool or something to mask out the image. This also only works for removing the black parts of an image, so it's not very specific or user friendly. Good luck, though, and let me know if you have any questions. Happy Blendering!

Cheers,

Graves Broderick

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort and replying in details. The problem is with the background it removed the inner color also (from eyes and the curve circle). I just need to remove the background black color and give a out line or stroke or border to the remaining image.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would achieve that with Blender, I'm sorry. I really can't recommend Photoshop enough for this application, it would make that whole process so much easier, but I understand if that is unavailable to you. I hope someone will be able to help!

Comment: Thanks a ton, I had been searching for hours, how to remove black background from vfx and this answer finally saved me.